# Customize the user interface in AD B2C custom policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

I am trying to customize the user interface for the app factor registration page

I changed the LoadURI to point to https://aikaan.z13.web.core.windows.net/index.html

I have enabled CORS to allow all methods for https://aikaanms.b2clogin.com and https://login.microsoftonline.com

[CORS enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mYap.png)

But when I run the policy I get an error

AADB2C90047: The resource 'https://aikaan.z13.web.core.windows.net/index.html' contains script errors preventing it from being loaded.
Correlation ID: 1cb22f3b-7cdf-43ab-9f9e-53fc37b13907
Timestamp: 2021-04-22 09:36:59Z

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that is what you need but we needed to activate the JS too

so in our `SignUpSignin.xml` we added

```xml
<RelyingParty>
    <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="SignUpOrSignIn" />
    <UserJourneyBehaviors>
        <ScriptExecution>Allow</ScriptExecution>
    </UserJourneyBehaviors>
```

Comment: yes that is done.

However later I figured out, the issue was CORS

I had to add "*" in Allowed headers and Exposed headers, while enabling CORS on Azure. 

After the change, it is working now